# Infopath Expression error phoneNumber

Tags: infopath, infopath-rules

Currently I'm working with Infopath in french version and trying to insert an expression and it doesn't work. I'm wondering if it's the syntax problem.

My source to do that :[The instruction to create the expression for phone Number field](https://digitalmacgyver.wordpress.com/2012/02/02/custom-rule-for-telephone-field-in-infopath-201-form/)

```
concat(sous-chaîne(traduire(.,"()-",""), 1, 2), sous-chaîne(traduire(.,"()-",""), 3, 3),"-", sous-chaîne(traduire(.,"()-",""), 6, 4))
```

[image: Print Screen]

[image: Print Screen]

[image: Print Screen]

Comment: What is the telephone format you are looking for?

Comment: I just want simple format like (xxx)-xxx-xxxx . prompt an error if the user didn't enter properly the format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following expression to get the format like (xxx)-xxx-xxxx

```
concat("(", substring(translate(., "()- ", ""), 1, 3), ")-", substring(translate(., "()- ", ""), 4, 3), "-", substring(translate(., "()- ", ""), 7, 4))
```

Also watchout for the double quotes as often HTML double quotes are different from which is supported in InfoPath. To be in the safer side, always copy the formula in notepad and change all the quotes then use in the InfoPath.